# could not get response for webservice even in postman

Tags: android, json, postman, svc

iam implementing  .svc web services but could not get success in response . Please let me know the issue

web service url is :
http://77.92.177.131/Focus8Library/TransactionService.svc/LoadVoucher

and we have to send json input :

json is :

```
"{
  ""iVoucherType"": 5635,
  ""sVoucherNo"": ""101973"",
  ""objLoadTrans"": {
    ""arrBodyIds"": null,
    ""arrBodyNames"": [
      ""Product"",
      ""Description"",
      ""Unit"",
      ""Quantity"",
      ""L-Sales Quotations"",
      ""Rate"",
      ""Gross"",
      ""Discount Amt"",
      ""Discount %"",
      ""sRemarks""
    ],
    ""arrFooterIds"": null,
    ""arrFooterNames"": [
      ""Scheme Discount"",
      ""Round Off"",
      ""Card Charges"",
      ""Special Discount""
    ],
    ""arrHeaderIds"": null,
    ""arrHeaderNames"": [
      ""sVoucherNo"",
      ""Date"",
      ""CustomerAC"",
      ""Currency"",
      ""Outlet"",
      ""Salesman"",
      ""Cost Center"",
      ""sNarration"",
      ""Delivery_Address"",
      ""Delivery_Terms"",
      ""Pay_Terms"",
      ""LPONo""
    ]
  },
  ""bByIds"": ""false""
}"
```

we have  to send fsessionid - Should be added in the request header

```
session id is :==>> 280520188522077721
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Volley JsonObjectRequest and my model is parsed with Gson library.
I have also implemented WCF webservice.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "simplePostExample", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]

Test simplePostExample(Test test);
```

Test is custom object.

it is working perfectly in my scenario.

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends JsonRequest<T> {

        private Class<T> mType;
        private String mEncodedCharSetProtocol = "utf-8";

        CustomJsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> type, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                      Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                    errorListener);
            this.mType = type;
        }


        @Override
        protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String parsed;
                try {
                    if (mEncodedCharSetProtocol != null) {
                        parsed = new String(response.data, mEncodedCharSetProtocol);
                    } else {
                        parsed = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    parsed = new String(response.data);
                }
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                return Response.success(gson.fromJson(parsed, mType),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }
        }
    }
```

Also include Gson library

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

I hope it will work.